# PHPUnit dynamic library warnings - image not found

Tags: php, macos, phpunit

I'm having some problems with phpunit on my mac.

When I run phpunit, I get the following errors

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas why? I've manually added mcrypt to my system using this guide - http://michaelgracie.com/2009/09/23/plugging-mcrypt-into-php-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-10-6-1/

I'm confused as to why its looking for an image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The interesting part is `Unable to load dynamic library`, not that with the image. Make sure, that you either don't try to load the extensions, or the extensions exists.

Comment: Running phpinfo() in a web browser shows that mcrypt.so and the others are all running fine. Very strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in a [forum thread](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=792), the directory needs to be in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

First run

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
$ php --version
```

You should get no more errors now.

Comment: Same error, but this solution doesn't work !! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288668/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-gearman-so

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with xhprof and php installed with josegonzalez' homebrew:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.23/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xhprof.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.23/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xhprof.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Turns out the problem was due to an extra line in the php.ini, probably a vestige from a previous install.

```
$ grep -RF xhprof .
./conf.d/ext-xhprof.ini:[xhprof]
./conf.d/ext-xhprof.ini:extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-xhprof/0.9.2/xhprof.so"
./php.ini:extension="xhprof.so" ; <-- this, why do I need to load xhprof twice?
```

Removing that line made the warning go away.

Comment: Same error, but that's not the problem. PHPUnit is calling an older version of PHP from outside of homebrew. Still fiddling with this...

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that php was updated from 5.3.26 to 5.3.27 but the modules were only in the /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/lib/php/extensions directory while php searched them in the /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.27/lib/php/extensions directory. I just had to copy the extensions folder over from the old 5.3.26 location:

rsync -arv /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/lib/php/extensions /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.27/lib/php

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've managed to solve my problem, but hopefully this helps someone else!