# XAMPP Apache won't start on port 81, unable to load dynamic library?

Tags: php, macos, apache, pdo, xampp

- XAMPP 5.6.3-0
- Mac Yosemite 10.10.5

I ran `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:81` and found that Dropbox was blocking it first, so I unlinked that (never use it). Now, when I run that command, it is empty.

If I run `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:80` I get:

```
httpd       75    root    4u  IPv6 0xaac1841fb411203d      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      532    _www    4u  IPv6 0xaac1841fb411203d      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Which I think is okay, since it's on a different port, right?

If I look inside the `/Applications/XAMPP/logs` for the error_log, ssl_request_log, and access_log there isn't anything logged since two months ago.

If I look inside the `php_error_log` I see this:

```
[08-Jan-2016 16:13:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I found a similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827880/phpunit-dynamic-library-warnings-image-not-found). I ran the command in the top answer (but obviously changed the dir path to mine), and it didn't work. I read the [forum with the link](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=792) he attached and someone said that on Mac is is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so i tried that as well, and it still doesn't work. I've tried restarting my computer and the osx-manager multiple times.

If I look inside the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/` directory, it doesn't have `php_pdo_mysql.dll` in there. Is it supposed to be in there already, or is it trying to load the library in there, and it's not working?

I get the dynamic library error every time I try to start it, so I'm guessing that is the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

For clarity, I have these lines in my httpd.conf file:

```
Listen 81
ServerName localhost:81
```

And in my `php.ini` file I have the `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` line uncommented, and it's the only extension uncommented. Does it depend on another extension? I'm so lost.

## Update

```
$ . /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp stopapache
$ XAMPP: Stopping Apache...not running

$ . /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp startapache
$ XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
$ XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
```

But running `lsof -nP -i :81` still gives me no results! =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to shut down the Apache server running on port 80 for this to work. I thought I wouldn't have to, since I had it configured to run on port 81. My only guess to why this happened is that I had it configured on port 80, started it, and then changed the configuration to 81 before shutting it down. I also had to comment out the `php_pdo_mysql` extension. I couldn't figure out that issue.