# On OS X, After installing php_pdo_pgsql, pgsql.so, Warning: dynamic library warnings - image not found

Tags: php, macos, postgresql

I want to use PostgreSQL as a database in my PHP Project on Mac OS X. Firstly, I looked at phpinfo whether or not pdo_pgsql install. There is no pdo_pgsql in phpinfo. Then, I installed by following [the guidence1](https://gist.github.com/giorgiofellipe/6282df335fd310de4108) and [guidence2](http://www.jasoncavett.com/blog/setting-up-oapp-osx-apache-postgresql-php-on-mavericks/)

Then I checked it by using this code:

```
php -m | grep pgsql
php --version
```

However, I showed this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I researched and found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827880/phpunit-dynamic-library-warnings-image-not-found) and then follow it by using this code:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
```

**P.S:**

- PHP Version is 5.5.38
- In /etc/php.ini:

  extension=pdo_pgsql.so 
  extension=pgsql.so

Unfortunely, I cannot solve this problem. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked waaaay to many times. Check your php.ini and uncoment the lib and restart the service, and presumably remove the prefix `php_` but check the extensions folder first for the correct name.

Comment: which php ? check that you are not running the osx distro php with the php.ini from the pgsql install

Comment: @Xorifelse It's already uncommented. Like this: extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so

Comment: @YvesLeBorg PHP 5.5.38

Comment: If you did as I asked, why is the error message reffering to `no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll` ? Specifically the `php_` Did you check the file exists?? Dit you change the correct php.ini?

Comment: I said before in /etc/php.ini. Do you think I looked at wrong location? @Xorifelse

Comment: if you installed php with brew, look in /usr/local/etc for all ini stuff. Also, modify your .bash_profile to path /usr/local/bin as top dog in the PATH env variable. This way, you get rid of other versions. Verify the brew install for both php and your pg-sql library, to ensure the paths are linked properly.

Comment: Apparently so, because the error message did not change. As I do not have *any* experience with Apple devices I expect the comment from @YvesLeBorg to hold key to your answer.

Comment: PHP and PostgreSQL (with the Python) works since I used before. I looked at in /usr/local/etc for all *.ini and there is two ini file: `/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini  /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini`

This is my .bash profile: 
`PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH" `

How I added with PATH env? 

Thanks

@YvesLeBorg

Comment: @Xorifelse been there, done that, got the T-shirt. On my desktop, i have a filed named osx_f'ups.txt where i log all arcane apple sh*** i have to do after ANY update.

Comment: add this line : `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` , they will be searched before the distribution paths. Reopen a new terminal, and issue `which php` to confirm you are running the one from /usr/local/bin. If all is well, `php --version` should be pointing to the ini in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini`. Edit that to your settings. Make a copy first ;)

Comment: i just followed the links for your install. I would *highly* recommend you stick to `brew` for any install on your mac, especially if you are running the latest El-Capitan.  So, `brew install php55-pdo-pgsql` would have been my choice for the pdo. Brew understands (much better than I) the intricacies of the OSX moving target. Your two links are Yosemite and Maverick procedures, probably broken on El-Capitan. Stick to brew.

Comment: It loaded successfully. Thanks a lot. @YvesLeBorg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @YvesLeBorg, I solved this problem. This is the solution of it:

I added this code on my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:‌​$PATH
```

Also, the warning said that .dll cannot find since Mac OS X is based on Unix. Therefore extension=module.dll for Windows extension=module.so for UniX. I uncommented both of them. Then I realized that and I commented .dll.

Moreover, There are three etc folder in OS X.

- /private/etc
- /usr/local/etc
- /etc

Find the true path. Again thanks to @YvesLeBorg, run this code and find true etc folder.

```
which php
```

Comment: glad i could help. Good luck with your project, have fun.